# Surface Type Cover: Context key?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, microsoft-surface

Is there a way to simulate (or does there exist an actual key combination, perhaps making use of the Fn key, that acts as) the context key on the Surface Type Cover?

I didn't realize until I tried to do real work with the Surface how much I *actually* use that key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean the **Context *Menu*** key?

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Note that this works if you have `F` keys enabled; otherwise it's `Fn` `Shift` `F10`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a program where <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> is mapped to something else, like all JetBrains IDEs, you have no way of simulating the <kbd>Context menu</kbd> with the surface cover.

A workaround is using a 3rd party app, like AutoHotkey, to map it to some hotkey.